# Rename and prefix filename with date and time

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am trying to prefix timestamp and add an extension to files using a script.
I have file *ABC* which I is being renamed to *ABC.txt*

```
DIRECTORY=`find /path/to/file -type f ! -name "*.*"`
NOW=$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S)

for file in $DIRECTORY; do

    mv "$file" "$file"_"${NOW}.txt"
    done
```

The output above works but as a suffix, if I switch it around

```
    mv "$file" "${NOW}"$file".txt"
```

I'm getting cannot *mv: cannot move`2019-10-18-231254/path/to/file/ABC.txt': No such file or directory*

I can see the issue is with the $Directory as this is calling the full path when doing the mv. Could someone please help simplify this?

Comment: You can get the filename from a path like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/965072/2519977. This may be a duplicate. The problem is that `$file` contains the whole path and not just the filename. If everything is happening in the same folder, the filename should suffice - if not you'd also have to extract the path. Or maybe `sed` could help as well...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest avoiding the loop over the `find` command's output for the reasons discussed here:

- [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697/why-is-looping-over-finds-output-bad-practice)

Instead, consider using `-execdir`, with a shell one-liner to remove the path components:

```
#!/bin/bash

export NOW=$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S)

find /path/to/file -type f ! -name '*.*' -execdir sh -c '
  for f; do echo mv "$f" "${NOW}_${f#./}"; done
' find-sh {} +
```

Remove the `echo` once you are happy that it is doing the right thing. Note that `NOW` needs to be exported so that its value is available in the `sh -c` subshell.

If your `find` implementation doesn't provide `-execdir`, then you can use `-exec` if you remove and replace the path explicitly:

```
find /path/to/file -type f ! -name '*.*' -exec sh -c '
  p="${1%/*}"; echo mv "$1" "$p/${NOW}_${1##*/}"
' find-sh {} \;
```

Comment: Great thanks for the help, It's prefixing as i required.

Comment: thank, it help me. In my case, my need is just to add timestamp prefix to archive files: `horodate_prefix=$(date +%Y%m%d_%HH%M)`   
`export file_name=${horodate_prefix}_save.tar.gz `  
`echo $file_name`  
`# create tar `  
`tar zcvf $file_name *.ext`

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU Parallel:

```
find /path/to/file -type f ! -name "*.*" -print0 |
  parallel -0 mv {} {//}/$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S)_{/}.txt
```

Please consider using ISO8601 for timestamps:

```
find /path/to/file -type f ! -name "*.*" -print0 |
  parallel -0 mv {} {//}/$(date +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S)_{/}.txt
```

Or:

```
find /path/to/file -type f ! -name "*.*" -print0 |
  parallel -0 mv {} {//}/$(date +%Y%m%dT%H%M%S)_{/}.txt
```

That means you can use a standardized ISO8601 parser for parsing the timestamp later.